# Extension of identity map

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $z$ be the identity map on unit circle $\Bbb T$. Extending $z$ to closed unit disc $\Bbb D$. The identity map on $\Bbb D$ is an extension of $z$. Is the continuous Extension of this certain function  unique?
Please give me the reference about it.

Comment: An extension is nearly never unique if you don't want additional properties.
Even the identity $f$ on $(0,\infty)$ does not have a unique extension to $[0,\infty)$, since every choice $f(0) = x \in \mathbb{R}$ is possible. If you want the extension to be continuous then it can be unique. In this case the answer shows that it is not unique.

Comment: @menag although it is tagged topology, so maybe the op wants its to be continuous, but I think that people should say what they want explicitly.

Comment: @menag I need uniqness of continuous extension.

Answer (score 8):

No. For instance $x\mapsto \lVert x\rVert^\alpha x$ are all pairwise different extensions when $\alpha\ge0$.

Answer (score 4):

No. For instance, letting this take place in the complex plane, the maps
$$
z \mapsto ze^{ai(1-|z|)}, \quad a \in \Bbb R
$$
will "spiral" inwards at different rates for different $a$.

Answer (score 1):

No. For any $p\in\mathbb D$, the function
$z\mapsto z+(1-|z|)p$ is continuous, and it maps the unit disk to itself.

Answer (score 0):

Extension means you are extending on domain not on co-domain. You can never extend a map from unit circle to itself to a disc. If you know homology then it is easy to see. Your extension map is from disc to disc but actual extension map should be from disc to circle.

Comment: What do you mean?